# Multiplicacion en vez de divison en python

Tags: python, depuración, calculo

En una calculadora de python en la que tu metes dos numeros y la primera letra de la operacion que quieras hacer (si quieres dividir pones d, multiplicar m, etc) al dividir, se multiplica, si pones 6, d, 2, en vez de salir 3 sale 12. A continuación el código:

```
num1 = int(input('Ingrese el primer numero -> '))
operacion = input('Ingrese la primera letra de la operacion que quiera hacer -> ').lower()
num2 = int(input('Ingrese el segundo numero -> '))

suma = num1 + num2
resta = num1 - num2
multiplicacion = num1 * num2
division = num1/num2

if operacion == 's':
    print(f'El resultado es {suma}')
elif operacion == 'r':
    print(f'El resultado es {resta}')
elif operacion == 'p' or 'm':
    print(f'El resultado es {multiplicacion}')
elif operacion == 'd':
    print(f'El resultado es {division}')
else:
    print('Ha ocurrido un error, vuelva a intentarlo')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisamente, el problema esta en la condicion

```
elif operacion == 'p' or 'm':
```

Debes sustituirla por

```
elif operacion == 'p' or operacion=='m':
```

El codigo no te da ningun error de ejecucion porque esta sintacticamente correcto. La condicional evalua una funcion or entre dos expresiones booleanas. En este caso el interprete de Python convierte la expresion

```
'm'
```

a un booleano, el cual se transforma en True. Puedes comprobarlo manualmente:

```
print(bool('m'))
>> True
```

Python convierte cualquier cadena de texto a booleano como True, excepto la cadena vacia:

```
print(bool('dfgbc'))
>> True
print(bool(''))
>> False
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta tan bien explicada 

Answer (score 4):

Si probases un poco el codigo de darias cuenta que nunca entra a dividir y se queda en multiplicar y con un poco de curiosidad buscarias como usar `or` correctamente

```
elif operacion == 'p' or operacion=='m':
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, poco después me dí cuenta